# Backbone route _extractParameters capturing an extra null parameter

Tags: regex, backbone.js

I have the following route in my Backbone router:

```
'surveys/:surveyId?:opts': 'SurveyList:Selected'
```

And the following handler that captures any route and republishes it on a message bus for my views to handle:

```
this.on('route', function() {
    PubSub.publish(Events.RouteChanged, {
        route: arguments[0],
        options: arguments[1]
    });
});
```

When the router matches the route `surveys/myTestId123?pageNum=2`, the expected behaviour is that `arguments[1]` would be an array of 2 arguments: `myTestId123` and `pageNum=2`.  However, it is actually an array with 3 arguments - the two aforementioned ones and a `null` value as the third.  I narrowed this down to the `_extractParameters` method, which matches the url fragment against a regular expression.  In this case, the regular expression is `/^surveys\/([^\/?]+)(?:\?([^\/?]+))?(?:\?([\s\S]*))?$/i`.

Interestingly enough, I get the correct parameters when the route is `surveys/:surveyId`, which in turn produces this regex: `/^surveys\/([^\/?]+)(?:\?([\s\S]*))?$/i`.

[Here is a fiddle showing the problem in action](https://jsfiddle.net/pw6q793d/).

Is this a problem with the regex that Backbone creates from my route, or a problem with the route itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just discovered the answer.  It looks like Backbone already does what I'm trying to do.  If I have the route `surveys`, it also provides a `null` parameter.  However, the regex it creates is as follows:

```
/^surveys(?:\?([\s\S]*))?$/i
```

This appears to already match querystring parameters, which explains why the shorter route works in my example above.  Those clever people at Backbone were one step ahead of me.

**Update:**

From the Backbone v1.1.1 change log:

> Backbone Routers now handle query params in route fragments, passing
>   them into the handler as the last argument. Routes specified as
>   strings should no longer include the query string ('foo?:query' should
>   be 'foo').